# Detecting geometry change between two line layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, change-detection

I have two line layers of the exact same features but I suspect there is a difference in some of geometry between the two.

Is there a way to simply detect change between the two layers?

I am not interested in the attribute change; I simply want to see the areas where there is a difference between the two layers.